# Pine script function return

Tags: pine-script

I'm confused by pine scripts returns from functions, why does this code show a `3` and not a `1`? Shouldn't execution stop as soon as possible?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test functions", overlay = true)

returnFunction() =>
    1
    2
    3
label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(returnFunction()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that’s returned by a multi-line function is the function’s last line (Pine Script Language Tutorial, n.d.). That line can either be an expression (like x + 10), a variable (x), or a variable declaration (x = 10).

[reference](https://kodify.net/tradingview/operators/function-declaration-operator/)